# Is there way to offset timezone in Cassandra using nodejs connectors?

Tags: node.js, datetime, cassandra, timezone

Cassandra server is storing times in UTC. It's offsetting times based on TZ environment when connecting via commandline.

However, when connecting via node-cassandra-cql, the times are coming back in UTC.

Is there a way to offset the db connection to a specific timezone or timezone offset?

Answer (score 0):

node-cassandra-cql is EOL, you should use the [DataStax Node.js driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver).

Both Cassandra timestamp and [Ecmascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) represent a single moment in time (without timezone information), so the date stored and retrieved is the same but you are seeing differences in the string representation of the date.

You can use Date methods to string represent it in another way or change the UTC offset or you can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) package to use a different timezone from the one in the server.

Comment: Basically: loop over rows and convert time columns. That is what you're staying? No way to set a timezone at the time of connection so datetimes are returned in desired timezone, eh?

And I'm aware of the EOL issues. That'll take a little more work to update (the calls are different). But we are moving that direction.

Comment: CQL3 Timestamps are stored as milliseconds since unix epoch, the same way a EcmaScript Date is internally represented. The Date returned by the driver is correct, if you want to give a different string representation of the Date than the EcmaScript default, you should use something to change it like the package to recommend it. You should not change the row values, you just change the string representation when you need it.

Comment: Correct. And that's exactly what I'm looking for. In Maria, I can set a timezone variable to get the data base represented within that specified timezone. I'm looking for the equivalent in Cassandra. cqlsh uses TZ='...' env variable. What does the Node connector(s) use?

Comment: I understand but in python you can specify the [tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) of a datetime, but this is not available in EcmaScript Date, that is why I recommend you to use a higher level wrapper like momentjs.